# VMware and Linux screen adjustment

Tags: linux, unix, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

I have installed Linux-Mint on my VMware Workstation8 but I don't know how to make its screen fit inside the VMware client screen even when I resize the VMware windows.

Comment: It works the other way around. Usually your monitors don't change size while you're working.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant resize the actual machine's screen to fit to the window size, not scale the image. @sunday's answer is correct, as I do that with VirtualBox sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, VMware doesn't support scaling in that fashion. You should try VirtualBox, as it has an option to Scale-To-Window.

Comment: Thanks, I know now, i will leave it as it is for no further time wasting and possible troubles

Comment: True, VMware doesn't have that function, only VBox does.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003

That's for windows but it's the same issue for linux. Basically you need to play with vmx file.